# How to translate svg element itself?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have having trouble translating the svg element.

Here is a sample of what I have

```
<svg transform="translate(500,150)">
   <g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

It seems that when I apply this translate, only the `<g>` gets translated. I have to extend the width of the svg big enough so that the `<g>` is still within the svg.

Is there a way to translate svg itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move a top-level SVG around within an HTML page, you need to use [CSS transform styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms), including vendor prefixes and length units, not the SVG transform attribute.

```
<svg style="-webkit-transform:translate(500px,150px);transform:translate(500px,150px)">
   <g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

(or use a stylesheet instead of inline CSS)

If your SVG is a nested element (i.e., within a larger SVG), than the transform attribute should work.

If that doesn't answer your question, create a [simple working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what's happening and also try to more clearly explain what you want to happen.